recording screen using opencv and pyautogui

Hello,
below is my script:
  import pyautogui
    import cv2
    import time
    import numpy as np
    
    def record_screen(filename, duration=30, width=1920, height=1080, fps=30):
        """Records the screen for a specified duration and saves it as a video file.
    
        Args:
            filename: Name of the output video file.
            duration: Duration of the recording in seconds.
            width: Width of the captured video frame.
            height: Height of the captured video frame.
            fps: Frames per second of the video.
        """
    
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')  # Video codec
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, fps, (width, height))
    
        start_time = time.time()
        while time.time() - start_time < duration:
            img = pyautogui.screenshot()
            img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            out.write(img)
            cv2.imshow('Screen Recorder', img)
    
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
    
        out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    # Example usage:
    filename = "D:\OneDrive\RECS\test-01.mp4"
    duration = 30  # Record for 30 seconds
    record_screen(filename, duration)

when i run it, i get the screen recorded as displayed in the attached screenshot. what am i doing wrong and how to adjust the script so that the recording goes on until i stop it myself?

that is as it should be. the window in which you show the screen is part of the screen. as such, visual recursion happens.
